# How to put Admob banner for iOS on bottom centre?

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I am using this code to put the banner ads on bottom left.

```
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                             self.view.frame.size.height -
                             CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height);
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner
                                             origin:origin];
```

How to position the banner at bottom center?

Comment: Did you make any attempt? You knew how to put it at the bottom. Calculate the proper `x` coordinate to center it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to add it as a subview after initialization:

```
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height - CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height);

bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner
                                                         origin:origin];
bannerView_.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.frame.size.height-CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height/2)
[self.view addSubview: bannerView_];
```

Comment: The question is how to center it instead of putting it in the bottom left.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, this code helped me center banner ad to the bottom.
The Google admob documentation helped as well.

```
func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
     bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     view.addSubview(bannerView)
     view.addConstraints(
        [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                            attribute: .bottom,
                            relatedBy: .equal,
                            toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide,
                            attribute: .bottom,
                            multiplier: 1,
                            constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
        attribute: .centerX,
        relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide,
        attribute: .centerX,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0)]
        )

    }
```